# Attaching an event to multiple elements at one go

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Say I have the following :

```
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");

//I want to do something as such as the following : 

$(a,b).click(function () {/* */}); // <= does not work

//instead of attaching the handler to each one separately
```

Obviously the above does not work because in the `$` function, the second argument is the [`context`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext), not another element.

So how can I attach the event to both the elements at one go ?

---

**[Update]**

[peirix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388018/jquery-attaching-an-event-to-multiple-elements-at-one-go/1388087#1388087) posted an interesting snippet in which he combines elements with the `&` sign; But something I noticed this :

```
$(a & b).click(function () { /* */ }); // <= works (event is attached to both)

$(a & b).attr("disabled", true); // <= doesn't work (nothing happens)
```

From what you can see above, apparently, the combination with the `&` sign works only when attaching events...?

Comment: did not work with jquery 1.7

Comment: What didn't?  The snippets I have in my question are all invalid.  Take a look at Gareth's answer for the correct one.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The [jQuery add method](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add#expr) is what you want:

> Adds more elements, matched by the given expression, to the set of matched elements

```
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");
var combined = a.add(b)
```

Comment: Wanted to add more than 1 element so I did var combined = a.add(b,c,d) it does not work you have to do a.add(b).add(c).add(d)

Answer (score 38):

Don't forget either that jQuery selectors support the CSS comma syntax. If you need to combine two arbitrary collections, everyone else's suggestions are on the mark, but if it's as simple as doing something to elements with IDs `a` and `b`, use `$('#a,#b')`.

Comment: yes I know about that, but my issue is when they are already in variables

Answer (score 16):

This question has already been answered, but I think a simpler more streamlined way to accomplish the same end would be to rely on the similarities between jQuery's and CSS's selector model and just do:

```
$("#a, #b").click(function () {/* */});
```

I use this frequently, and have never seen it not work (I can't speak for jQuery versions before 1.3.2 though as I have not tested this there).  Hopefully this helps someone someday.

---

**UPDATE:** I just reread the thread, and missed the comment you made about having the nodes in question already saved off to variables, but this approach will still work, with one minor tweek.  you will want to do:

```
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");
$(a.selector+", "+b.selector).click(function () {/* */});
```

One of the cool things that jquery does is that it adds a few jquery specific properties to the node that it returns (selector, which is the original selector used to grab that node is one of them).  You may run into some issues with this if the selector you used already contained commas.  Its also probably arguable if this is any easier then just using add, but its a fun example of how cool jquery can be :).

Comment: This approach will make jquery to re-look the whole DOM-tree for the given selector. It's additional overhead.

Answer (score 8):

You could just put them in an array:

```
$.each([a, b], function()
{
    this.click(function () { });
});
```

Comment: Oops, mixed up the syntax with the other each() - try now

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use an array? This works on my side:

```
$([item1, item2]).on('click', function() {
      // your logic
});
```

Comment: This only works if item1 and item2 are DOM elements not jQuery objects: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray.

Comment: @SteelRat, hmm.. I'm trying to remember what I was testing it on. But it was long time ago.
So if it's jQuery object then it should work with:
$([item1[0], item2[0]]).on('click', function() {
      // your logic
});

Answer (score 2):

I just tried messing around with this, and found something very cool:

```
$(a & b).click(function() { /* WORKS! */ });
```

supersweet!

**Edit:** Now I feel really embarrassed for not testing this properly. What this did, was actually to put the click event on *everything*... Not sure why it does that, though...

Comment: @peirix: `&` is for bitwise operating on numbers.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the whole page got the click event? It should just not be added, then, shouldn't it?

Comment: @peirix: `DOMElementA & DomElementB` results in a value of `0` since each argument is `NaN`. jQuery checks if the argument passed is "falsey" (FYI `0` is falsey) and defaults to operating on the entire `document` if it finds such a value.

Comment: Is that deliberate? That if something is falsy, it should just run it on the whole document? Sounds very strange, and very susceptible to unknown errors...

Comment: @peirix: jQuery is emulating "default" parameters. It wants to support calling `$()` with no arguments and having it run on the entire `document`. It has been in there for as long as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make up a class name and give each element that you want to work with that class. Then you can bind the event to all elements sharing that class.

```
<p><a class="fakeClass" href="#">Click Me!</a></p>

<p><a class="fakeClass" href="#">No, Click Me!</a></p>

<div class="fakeClass">Please, Click Me!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".fakeClass").on("click", function () {
            alert("Clicked!");
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: sweet and simple.

```
var handler = function() {
    alert('hi!');
}
$.each([a,b], function() {
    this.click(handler);
}
```

BTW, this method is not worth the trouble.

If you already know there are just two of these methods, then I guess the best bet would be

```
a.click(handler);
b.click(handler);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$("[name=ONE_FIELD_NAME], [name=ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME]").keypress(function(e){alert(e.which);});
```