# Can i consolidate function calls in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following and would like to be able to use one function only preferably...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#home_p1").editInPlace({
        url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
    });

$("#home_p2").editInPlace({
        url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
    });

$("#home_p3").editInPlace({
        url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
    });
});
```

This could go to 15 or 20 instances on some pages...is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery : Attaching an event to multiple elements at one go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388018/jquery-attaching-an-event-to-multiple-elements-at-one-go)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the different elements with a comma:

```
$("#home_p1, #home_p2, #home_p3").editInPlace({
    url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
});
```

Or you can add a class to all your elements and use a class selector:

```
$(".someClass").editInPlace({
    url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
});
```

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)

Comment: Didier - Outstanding, thanks - will accept when I can - why have to wait to accept btw?

Comment: The let time to people to provide other answers that might be also good or better, it's not always the first answer the better (except in this case of course ^^). Anyway, glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

2/3 options ...

1) combine the selectors :

```
$("#home_p1,#home_p1").editInPlace({
    url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
});
```

2) use a class :

```
$(".yourclass").editInPlace({
    url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
});
```

3) If your IDs match a pattern as in your example :

```
$("[id^=home_]").editInPlace({
    url: './include_eip_77994477/eip.php',
});
```

Comment: Option 3 is a good one if you are not able to add classes to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to your #home_px elements and target it using the class? The urls are all the same in your example, but if they were different you could use data.

```
$(".element").editInPlace({
    url: $(this).data('url'),
});

<div class="element" data-url="./include_eip_77994477/eip.php"></div>
```

Hope that helps :)